# Embed Web Page with Fluent UI Northstar

Tags: components, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I am trying to use the Embed component in Fluent UI Northstar to embed a SharePoint Web Page:

```
<Embed
  iframe={{
    allowFullScreen: true,
    src: "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/Lists/ListName",
    frameBorder: 0,
    height: '400px',
    width: '711.11px',
  }}
/>
```

The page doesn't get loaded, all I see in the page is a play icon:

[image]

What am I missing?

The component is used within the same SharePoint site, so the user is already authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. I had to give the Embed component a width and height, and use the `active` prop to have the iframe load automatically without pressing "play".